# Stacking countries

Tags: pattern, geography

**This is a stack of countries:**

> $Russia$
>   $Gabon$
>   $Germany$
>   $Indonesia$

**Values of the countries:**

> $Russia = 8$
>   $Gabon = 12$
>   $Germany = 8$
>   $Indonesia = 6$

[image]

**Question:**

> Try to find a value for $Spain$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

answer

> Spain = red + yellow = 1 + 4 = 5 if you don't count the thing in the middle of its flag, 21 if you do (all 6 colours involved)

explanation

> country = sum of color values on its flag, e.g. Russia = red + blue + white = 1 + 2 + 5 = 8

Comment: Correct! But RED + YELLOW = 5

Comment: oops, my math... @Matti